# How to print arraylist in several lines instead of one long

Tags: java

```
//I have written this method but I don't know how to proceed. 

public static void print(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i));
```

Comment: `println`........

Comment: `println` is an equivalent of `print` which adds `\n` at the end of the line (hence the name... ~ `print\n`)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle to be picky, it adds the JVM's configured line separator, which is often `\n`, but could be anything else (e.g. `\r\n` on Windows).

Comment: I believe it’s short for “print line”. `ln` has been taken over from standard libraries for other programming languages including Pascal.

Answer (score 2):

By using

```
System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

instead of

```
System.out.print(list.get(i));
```

the `println` method adds a linebreak after what you print.

Comment: System.out.println(list.get(i)); or System.out.print(list.get(i)+"\n");

Comment: Ankit, why would one do that? it doesn't make the code clearer, just messier.

Comment: just an alternative...seems the user is newbie stucking at small points.. Help him to show him alternatives :)

Comment: yes, but that is not "an alternative". to prevent having to do something like that, println was created.

Comment: okay buddy ;) You are right